# Drupal Tableselects

Tags: mysql, drupal

I can (finally!!!) set a query to return results for a checkbox(es) set within a collapsible fieldset in Drupal 7- however when I try to put it into a tableselect, I get no results. Would someone be able to check out this code and see if you can tell me why? I also have a screen shot of both results- but since I am new here it won't allow me to post it.

```
$form = array();

$secnum = 1;
  $result = db_query('SELECT s.secser_id, s.ser_name FROM {secser} s WHERE s.sec_num = :secnum', array(':secnum' => $secnum));
  $options = array();
  foreach ($result as $record) {
    $options[$record->secser_id] = $record->ser_name;
  }

$form['secser']['1'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Basic Sanitation'),
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
);

$form['secser']['1']['secser'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Choices'),
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#multiple' => TRUE,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#description' => t('choose!'),
);

$form['secser']['2'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Community Systems'),
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  );

  $secnum = 2;
  $result = db_query('SELECT s.secser_id, s.ser_name FROM {secser} s WHERE s.sec_num = :secnum', array(':secnum' => $secnum));
  $opt2 = array();
  foreach ($result as $record) {
    $opt2[$record->secser_id] = $record->ser_name;
  }

$header = array(
  'ser_name' => t('Choose Service(s)'),
  );

$form['secser']['2']['secser'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#title' => t('Community Systems'),
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => array($opt2),
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried running your code, but it looks like your options are an array which contains another array.

```
#options' => array($opt2),
```

because $opt2 is an array, this should be:

```
#options' => $opt2,
```

the same way you have the options set up in your checkboxes

Comment: I tried not putting the extra array($variable) but then nothing showed up. It's definitely a strings/objects/array issue- I'm still working through some documentation to try to understand it better.

Comment: if you're using the devel module, try adding `dpm()` in a few places, e.g. `foreach ($result as $record) {
    dpm($record);
    $opt2[$record->secser_id] = $record->ser_name;
  }
  dpm($opt2);`
that way you can see what each variable contains through the execution